# Attach .jpg screenshot to Outlook mail

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I created a form that contains an attachment field that screenshots are attached to in .jpg format.

I am trying to send emails from the form.

I would like to attach the screenshots to the email, (the one that is already attached on the form).

I tried using the .attachment.add me.attachmentfield. This is not attaching anything to the email.

Also I am using a combobox to select a person to send the email to, (this is stored in another table along with an email address). I am unable to populate the To box in the email with the email address of the individual selected.

Comment: The image must first be exported out of the database and saved as an image file then that file can be attached to the email. Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382384/ms-access-how-to-export-attachments-images-with-a-given-name-to-a-folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually an Access attachment field is not an email attachment. Access doesn't have a build in email client, so you must use an email client library like CDO or the Outlook Object library:

```
Public Function SendEmail(strRecipients As String, strSubject As String, _
       Optional strBody As String, Optional strFilePath As String, _
       Optional strFileExtension As String) As String

    On Error GoTo ProcError

    Dim myObject As Object
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim strFullPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strAttachPath As Variant
    Dim intAttachments As Integer

    Set myObject = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myItem = myObject.CreateItem(0)

    With myItem
        .Subject = strSubject
        .To = strRecipients

        If Len(Trim(strBody)) > 0 Then
            .body = strBody
        End If

        If Len(Trim(strFileExtension)) = 0 Then
            strFileExtension = "*.*"
        End If

        If Len(strFilePath) > 0 Then
            strFullPath = strFilePath & "\" & strFileExtension

            If Len(Trim(strFullPath)) > 0 Then  'An optional path was included
                strFileName = Dir(strFullPath)
                Do Until strFileName = ""
                    intAttachments = intAttachments + 1
                    strAttachPath = (strFilePath & "\" & strFileName)
                    .Attachments.add (strAttachPath)
                    ' Debug.Print strAttachPath
                    strFileName = Dir()
                Loop
            End If
        End If

        .Send
        SendEmail = "Message placed in outbox with " & intAttachments & " file attachment(s)."
    End With

ExitProc:
    Set myItem = Nothing
    Set myObject = Nothing
    Exit Function
ProcError:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
               vbCritical, "Error in SendMail Function..."
    SendEmail = "A problem was encountered attempting to automate Outlook."
    Resume ExitProc

End Function
```

Use Field.SaveToFile to dump the Access attachment to a temp file.